# Creating Multiple folders in sharepoint 2010 custom list at a time

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list with name  "Customers". Client having around 900 customers. He wants to create a folder for every customer. he has given customers list to me in a Excel sheet. How can we create multiple folders at a time or easily ( not creating folders one by one).

One more thing is he wants to give folder level permission to every customer on their respective folder.

How can we achieve this using code or OOB or Designer. Please help me..

Thanks & Regards,

Prasad Kommuru

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

$spAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
$mylist = (Get-SPWeb -identity http://portal.sharepoint.com -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment).Lists["LargeList"]

for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++)
{
    $folder = $mylist.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
    $folder["Title"] = "folder$i"
    $folder.Update();
    for($j=1; $j -le 10; $j++)
    {
        $s1folder = $mylist.AddItem($folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, 
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
        $s1folder["Title"] = "subfolder$j"
        $s1folder.Update();
         for($k=1; $k -le 10; $k++)
        {
            $s2folder = $mylist.AddItem($s1folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, 
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
            $s2folder["Title"] = "subsubfolder$k"
            $s2folder.Update();

```
        for($l=1; $l -le 50; $l++)
        {

            #Create item

            $newItem = $mylist.AddItem($s2folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl,
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::File, $null)
            $newItem["Title"] = "Item $i $j $k $l"
            $newItem["FirstName"] = "FirstName $i $j $k $l"
            $newItem["LastName"] = "LastName $i $j $k $l"
            $newItem["Company"] = "Company $i $j $k $l"
            $newItem.Update()
        }
    }   
}
```

}
Stop-SPAssignment $spAssignment

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Try the below options

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10552/
 or

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2011/03/21/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-create-a-folder-in-document-libraries-and-lists.aspx